# How to unit test a Service using Circuit Breaker without activating the Circuit Breaker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-cloud, resilience4j

I add a **Circuit Breaker** in my service class, but I noticed all my unit tests are failing after that.

- Is there a good way to test a service implementing a **Circuit Breaker** without breaking previous unit tests
- Is there a way to mock the **Circuit Breaker** or disable it while running my tests
- Should **Circuit Breaker** should be test only in integration tests.

Here is my code:

```
public class PersonService {

    private final CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;
    
    public PersonService(CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory) {
        this.circuitBreakerFactory = circuitBreakerFactory;
    }

    public List<Item> getPersonItems() {
        return circuitBreakerConfiguration.create("CB_Service").run(() -> apiCall.getItems(), exception -> {
            log.error("An error occurs");
            throw new ItemServiceException("No Item available");
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably reset the circuit breaker after tripping it in tests you know are incrementing the counter

We use resilience4j and it has a `reset()` method see - https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples#reset-circuitbreaker.

We use it in the `@AfterEach` for tests CircuitBreakerUtil is just a wrapper for the [CircuitBreakerRegistry](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples#override-the-registrystore).

```
@AfterEach
public void stopCircuitBreakerTripping() {
    CircuitBreakerUtil.get("Breaker").reset();
}
```